# Fastest way for Australian to get Brazil Visa

Tags: visas, australian-citizens, brazil

I am due to fly into Brazil leaving Melbourne on 30th October, arriving in Rio on the 1st November.

I've been trying to find a way to get a visa this week. I am willing to pay extensive costs to do so quickly. What is the absolute fastest way for me to get a tourist visa into Brazil ideally in under a week?

Comment: You're totally out of luck  :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Brazilian Embassy web site](http://camberra.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/tourist_visa.xml) suggests that a tourist visa can take up to fifteen days to process. It also says

> Whether applying in person, by post, through a visa agency and/or
>   courier service, visas will be processed in the order of arrival. **The
>   Embassy does not provide urgent or priority services**, and as such no
>   expediting fees are incurred by the Embassy.

<sup>(my emphasis)</sup>

Agencies and courier services will not be able to help. The web site has this to say:

> The Embassy of Brazil in Canberra is not affiliated with nor does it
>   endorse any visa agencies and/or courier services. All such agencies
>   receive identical treatment by the Embassy's Consular section.

At best you can lodge documents in person in Canberra or Sydney, for which you will need an appointment, bookable through the web site.

I speculate that a straightforward application with all required documentation (checklist on the web site) *might* be processed faster than fifteen days, but I doubt you could get anyone to commit to that.

There is no telephone support for visas at the Brazilian embassy or consulate, so you'll be limited to their turnaround times for email if you want to ask questions ahead of time.

Good luck

Comment: The consulate in Sydney [does not process applicants from Victoria](http://sydney.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/jurisdiction.xml), so Canberra is the only choice

Answer (score 4):

Effective November 21, 2017, [Brazil plans to introduce electronic visas for Australian citizens](http://www.turismo.gov.br/%C3%BAltimas-not%C3%ADcias/8196-emiss%C3%A3o-de-vistos-eletr%C3%B4nicos-come%C3%A7a-em-novembro.html) (link in Portuguese), which will be processed within 72 hours.  Google Translate:

> From November 21, Australian tourists wishing to visit Brazil will be
>   able to apply for an entry visa in the country through an electronic
>   document issuing system. The visa must be issued within 72 hours after
>   the request is made by the tourist. The benefit is also valid for
>   business trips.

Unfortunately this comes a few weeks too late for you...

Comment: Downvote, srsly?  I understand this won't help the original poster, but this Q&A will still be around next month.